How to make an S-class multitool spawn?
I'm following several guides that should lead me to S-class multitool locations (I also tried with No Man's Sky Glyphs Exchange), but with no avail.
Yes, I'm in the correct galaxy.
Yes, I'm following the instructions.
Most of them suggests to make a restore point in a specific planet and then lead to a specific location in order to find the S-class multitool, but I always find a different one. Or even the correct multitool, but with a lower class.
I also tried reloading again and again, but the expected one never spawns.
What am I doing wrong? What am I supposed to do to get an S-class multitool from a known location that has an S-class multitool?
I'm starting to think that a recent update may have changed multitool spawns.

I managed to find 3 S-class with different coordinates, still don't understand the logic.

that is overly complex and I don't have time to summarize everything now (I don't know what you already know either). Can you please look here and see if you find what you were missing?

@Ꮢedacted I followed that guide too, and this is where I'm lost: "Reloading and checking that cabinet again will not spawn a different tool in that tier. Once a particular tool is assigned to pop up in that cabinet from a particular pool, that's the only tool that will spawn in that cabinet from that pool." but I often get a different multitool. Aren't they always guaranteed to be S-class for a specific cabinet if I follow the instructions?

That means two things: first, if you somehow save AFTER checking the cabinet, you are stuck: that cabinet will show the same tool forever, unless you somehow "purge" it from history (the game can track only a finite amount of data, that is why over a very long time old systems you no longer visit WILL fade from your list). Second, the first time checked the cabinet pulls form some random pools, but if you check the tutorial the cabinet can spawn something from its own class or the two adjacent ones (this means a S class can still spawn an A)

Third.... Patches can change generation (I wouldn't be surprised if the Space station overhaul broke most old coordinates related to stations for example) and some even report that some console version seems to give different results. So, good luck. I will keep using my Atlas scepter and upgrade it to S class as soon as I can find some time to waste on the boring nanite refining / pirate station jumping. But  you should see the positive side: maybe you will be the one to prove that the Incenerator is still spawning in the game...

@Ꮢedacted oh ok, I may have tried to "refresh" the pool by creating new restore points after checking the cabinet. Guilty. But I definitely got multitools from different classes. In that case what's the solution? I tried reloading and always the same multitool spawned.

@Ꮢedacted yeah I'm playing on PS5 and I think that something may change from PC users. But now I'm happy, I finally managed to get an alien S-class. Btw you can post that 3 points as a real answer, because that's exactly what I needed to know.

You should switch to Genshin and spare you the pain: there, all artifacts come in the same class, no matter what. F "WHY RNG YOU HATE ME" class to be precise.

@Ꮢedacted LOL I will, no worries, that's on my TODO list :D

First of all, you should probably check this guide to see if you understand the procedure correctly.
I will list some of the common causes for failure:

first, if you save after checking a cabinet, then that cabinet is "stuck" and will always show the same multitool from that specific pool no matter what (unless you switch to a different pool for example by going to a different planet, reloading the game and checking again). The game internally saves many things and apparently this information is persisted too.
second, while it is true that cabinets have a "class" in a way, it is also true that they can randomly spawn tools from the two adjacent classes too. This means that a B class could spawn tools in A and C class too. Basically, it is not guaranteed that you will get an S on first try: some save data scumming may be required.
third: PATCHES. Updates have changed the world generation multiple time and often this ended up changing the tool spawning too. In some extreme cases, not only the cabinet could offer a different pool now... the entire outpost could be gone (usually happens only for VERY old addresses).
fourth: I can't verify this info, but there are some claim about pools being different in some case depending on the platform you play on

It is a pity that you probably missed the Atlas Scepter. Had you got that one... I would have just told you to reload until you got a good slot placement at the quicksilver vendor, upgrade it to S class and... spare you the hunt.

Ok, going to a different planet to switch pool reloads the cabinet (after a reload), that's a good information. But what do you mean I have missed the Atlas Scepter?

@pinckerman Did you play the last expedition? Was your usual time limited reward. You can get other types of staves in the game but not that specific one

@pinckerman just to be clear, talking about this one link here

Nope, I haven't played a single expedition unfortunately. Yep, that's essentially why I'm hunting for a decent multitool
